# Applying log on images and turning into grayscale

Tags: python

I am trying to calculate the log of two images and then subtracting a group of another image log from that.
It looks like log(1550_N/1050_R_N)-log(1450_N/1050_R_N) where 1550, 1050, 1450 are wavelengths and I need to create a loop to calculate this. For every image 1550_N the denominator should be 1050_R_N where N matches. I have written the below code but its not able to match the N part of both the images taken from 1550 and 1050 directory.

```
for filename_1550 in os.listdir(dir_name_1550):
          img_1550 = cv2.imread(os.path.join(dir_name_1550, filename_1550))

          name1 = filename_1550.rsplit('.', 1)[0]
          for filename_1050 in os.listdir(dir_name_1050):
             name2 = filename_1050.rsplit('.', 1)[0]
              if name1 == name2:
                 img_1050 = cv2.imread(os.path.join(dir_name_1050, filename_1050))

         # Apply log transformation method
         c_1550 = 255 / np.log(1 + np.max(img_1550))
         c_1050 = 255 / np.log(1 + np.max(img_1050))
         log_image_1550 = c_1550 * (np.log(img_1550 + 1))
         log_image_1050 = c_1050 * (np.log(img_1050 + 1))

        # Specify the data type so that
        # float value will be converted to int
         log_image_1550 = np.array(log_image_1550, dtype=np.uint8)
         log_image_1050 = np.array(log_image_1050, dtype=np.uint8)
         result1 = log_image_1550-log_image_1050
         print(result1)
         plt.imshow(result1)
         plt.show() '''
```